# How to slideToggle Selectize.js dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate, selectize.js

I'm using the awesome [Selectize.js plugin](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js), and I'm trying to add a simple slide animation when the dropdown is opened using jQuery. And I also change the position to static.

**http://jsfiddle.net/TAuEH/1/**

I changed a this:

```
/**
* Shows the autocomplete dropdown containing
* the available options.
*/
open: function() {
  var self = this;

  if (self.isLocked || self.isOpen || (self.settings.mode === 'multi' && self.isFull())) return;
  self.focus(true);
  self.isOpen = true;
  self.refreshClasses();
  self.$dropdown.css({visibility: 'hidden', display: 'block'});
  self.positionDropdown();
  self.$dropdown.css({visibility: 'visible'});
  self.trigger('dropdown_open', this.$dropdown);
},

/**
* Closes the autocomplete dropdown menu.
*/
close: function() {
  var self = this;

  if (!self.isOpen) return;
  self.$dropdown.hide();
  self.setActiveOption(null);
  self.isOpen = false;
  self.refreshClasses();
  self.trigger('dropdown_close', self.$dropdown);
},
```

By this:

```
/**
* Shows the autocomplete dropdown containing
* the available options.
*/
open: function() {
  var self = this;

  if (self.isLocked || self.isOpen || (self.settings.mode === 'multi' && self.isFull())) return;
  self.focus(true);
  self.isOpen = true;
  self.refreshClasses();
  self.$dropdown.slideDown();
  self.positionDropdown();
  self.trigger('dropdown_open', this.$dropdown);
},

/**
* Closes the autocomplete dropdown menu.
*/
close: function() {
  var self = this;

  if (!self.isOpen) return;
  self.$dropdown.slideUp();
  self.setActiveOption(null);
  self.isOpen = false;
  self.refreshClasses();
  self.trigger('dropdown_close', self.$dropdown);
},
```

Well, as you see, I'm afraid it does not open properly, and does not do the slideup animation when you close it... anyone has better idea to do it?

Any advice, tip or help will be appreciated, and if you need more info i'll edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any change on the plugin code, you can try using the events `onDropdownOpen` and `onDropdownClose` and force an animation.

It's a bit hacky, but it works.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sel').selectize({
        create: false,
        sortField: 'text',
        onDropdownOpen: function () {
            $(".selectize-dropdown").hide().slideToggle();
        },
        onDropdownClose: function () {
            $(".selectize-dropdown").show().slideToggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/cHxcZ/

### EDIT

In the previous version there is an issue when you try to close it pressing the input again, solved using `stop`.

Ref:

> When .stop() is called on an element, the currently-running animation
>   (if any) is immediately stopped. If, for instance, an element is being
>   hidden with .slideUp() when .stop() is called, the element will now
>   still be displayed, but will be a fraction of its previous height.
>   Callback functions are not called.
>
> If more than one animation method is called on the same element, the
>   later animations are placed in the effects queue for the element.
>   These animations will not begin until the first one completes. When
>   .stop() is called, the next animation in the queue begins immediately.
>   If the clearQueue parameter is provided with a value of true, then the
>   rest of the animations in the queue are removed and never run.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sel').selectize({
        create: false,
        sortField: 'text',
        onDropdownOpen: function ($dropdown) {
            $dropdown.stop().hide().slideToggle();
        },
        onDropdownClose: function ($dropdown) {
            $dropdown.stop().show().slideToggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/cHxcZ/1/

Comment: Thanks, it works! But there is a problem when you try to close it pressing the input again... Can you correct this?

Comment: Another idea: Selectize adds a "dropdown-active" class. You could use CSS3 transitions to perform the animation without JS. I don't have time now, but I'll can try to work up an example in the day or so.

Comment: @brianreavis thanks for the stop suggestion, fo the CSS3 it's a solution but can lose cross browser support?

Comment: Great! but I'm afraid there is a issue in the second version too. When you press the input again to close it, does not close. Any fix for this?

Comment: Perfect!, but the last thing: when you close it pressing the input, it still appears opened (white color and with the arrow pointing to the top).

Comment: I think it must be used the blur method, but I can't find the right moment :-(

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward, look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/cHxcZ/7/ I've almost fixed. The problem is that it flashes a little when you close it...